# Laravel build locally and auto deploy to remote server

Tags: laravel, continuous-deployment

My web application are built on latest laravel framework with it's front end task and dependencies are managed through gulp, node, npm and bower.

My remote hosting server basically supports git only and does not support nodejs and npm. So currently I am building it locally and deploying it manually via ftp.

So, is their any tools that simply track the changes on locally build file and uploads the changes on the remote? Or may be there are better ways to do it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing could be fixed by committing your locally built files.

If it supports git and you have ssh access - set your remote repository local machine. Commit your local build files and push to a remote repository. Pull changes from remote repository on remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I was stuck with ftp and using Laravel.

To aliviate the agony of using ftp, I found this tool called `dploy`.

It simulates `git` in ftp, so you commit locally or to your remote repository, and `dploy` will take care of synchronizing your local build with your live server.

https://github.com/LeanMeanFightingMachine/dploy

I hope it helps.